# How to override editor-services

Tags: monaco-editor

I'm trying to have a custom way of implementing go-to-definition and that requires to override the editor-services, especially `openEditor()`, and `findModel()` methods, as far as I saw.

I tried following this comment:
https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/291#issuecomment-450706479
But couldn't run it in monaco's playground since there's no override for `findModel`.

I tried to add it to the playground so it would look like that:

```
monaco.languages.register({ id: 'mySpecialLanguage' });

monaco.languages.registerDefinitionProvider('mySpecialLanguage', {
    provideDefinition: function(model, position, cancellationToken) {
        return {
            uri: monaco.Uri.parse('http://a/different/file.txt'),
            range: new monaco.Range(3, 1, 3, 1)
        };
    }
});

var editorService = {
    openEditor: function() {
        alert(`open editor called!` + JSON.stringify(arguments));
    },
    resolveEditor: function() {
        alert(`resolve editor called!` + JSON.stringify(arguments));
    },
    findModel:function(editor, data) {
        alert(`resolve editor called!` + JSON.stringify(arguments));
    }
};

monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
    value: '\n\Go to definition on this text',
    language: 'mySpecialLanguage'
}, { editorService: editorService });
```

But that doesn't work either, as it doesn't run the findModel implementation here and logs in the console the error that the model doesn't exist.

So I was looking to see how does the third argument in `monaco.editor.create()` looks like and how it should behave. That third argument is (?Override: IEditorOverrideServices).

[The monaco docs aren't helpful](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.ieditoroverrideservices.html) and the TypeScript definition of it is too vauge:

```
export interface IEditorOverrideServices {
    [index: string]: any;
}
```

So how should it really be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution at the end was:

```
const editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container")!, {
    model: monaco.editor.createModel(value, 'python', monaco.Uri.parse('file:///users/gilad/monaco-languageclient/example/lib/python3/main.py')),
    glyphMargin: true,
    lightbulb: {
        enabled: true
    },
});


const editorService = (editor as any)._codeEditorService;
const openEditorBase = editorService.openCodeEditor.bind(editorService);
if(openEditorBase){

}
  
editorService.openCodeEditor = async (input: any, source: any, sideBySide: any) => {
    debugger 
    const result = await openEditorBase(input, source);
    if (result === null) {
        const fullPath = input.resource.path
        const lineNumber = input.options.selection.startLineNumber

        alert("file is at " + fullPath + ":" + lineNumber )
    }
    return result; // always return the base result
};
```

Comment: Does your solution still work in monaco-editor >= 0.26? I can't get this to work.

Comment: @Grillparzer, yeah, and im using `@monaco-editor/react`