# How to open embedded editors (e.g. peek references) in read-only mode with Monaco?

Tags: monaco-editor

I use a Monaco editor in a web application. The text models are provided [lazily via HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65663434/4384672). Now I want to show some of the resolved text models as read-only. It is clear how to open a Monaco "main editor" in [read-only mode](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.IEditorOptions.html#readOnly). Based on the text models URI I can decide whether it should be read-only or not, so I can configure the editor accordingly.

*However, how can I set an embedded editor (the inline editor opening up after a "peek definition", "peek references", etc.) to read-only independently of the "main editor"?*

A quite ugly workaround is to reset the value on every content change of the respective text model shown in the embedded editor. But clearly this is neither efficient nor nice.

```js
// model is a monaco.editor.ITextModel that should be readonly
model.onDidChangeContent(() => {
  if (model.getValue() !== content) {
    model.setValue(content);
  }
});
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When opening a peek window, a new editor will be created. This will cause the `monaco.editor.onDidCreateEditor` event to fire. Once the new editor has its model set, you can update the `readOnly` option:

```js
monaco.editor.onDidCreateEditor(newEditor => {
    newEditor.onDidChangeModel(e => {
        newEditor.updateOptions({
            readOnly: true
        });
    });
});
```